# Get Mouse Scroll Wheel Value in Unreal Engine 5 C++

Tags: c++, scroll, mouse, unreal-engine5, unreal

I'm setting up the mouse scroll wheel to zoom the camera in and out for a top-down game. I've gotten the input action setup to use the mouse wheel axis in the input context mapping, however in my `OnZoomTriggered` method I'm trying to find a method to get the scroll direction and velocity but I'm not seeing anything like that. For the left-click the template uses `GetHitResultUnderCursor` to get the click position, but I"m not seeing anything similar for the mouse scroll velocity. I'm trying to get the scroll velocity and increase or decrease the camera boom length based on that but I cannot find out how to get the mouse scroll velocity.

Does anyone know what I'm missing here?

Comment: So I manged to get this working by tracking two boolean values one for scroll up and scroll down and then just used a constant value to modify the camera boom length each time an event is fired. It isn't as elegant as I was hoping, but it works.